# How can i set date validation limit to 32 in play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I am developing an app here in Nepal, so i have to go with the local time and store the date as per Nepali calendar. According to Nepali calendar there the date limit to 32 **"32/12/2015"**. There's no problem while binding the date till 31, as i go through 32 it shows **"error.invalid"** error in the form. 
Is there any solution to limit the date to 32. 
sorry for bad grammar and Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention language which you use developing your app.

In Java you could create custom data formatter to bind values in form. Below is example how to write one:

```java
package example.formatters;

import play.data.format.Formatters.SimpleFormatter;    
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatter extends SimpleFormatter<Date>{

    @Override
    public Date parse(String value, Locale locale) throws ParseException {

        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        if(isStringDate(value)){
            return convertStringToDate(value);
        }

        throw new ParseException(value, 0); //throw exception if value is not proper date
    }    

    @Override
    public String print(Date d, Locale locale) {
        return convertDateToString(d);
    }
}
```

After implementing custom formatter you need to register it for datatype (for example in Global class of your application):

```java
package app;

import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.Logger;
import java.util.Date;
import example.formatters.DateFormatter;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        Formatters.register(java.util.Date.class, new DateFormatter());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Pawel. I did it using transient string field and converted date in controller.